# Gatsby: Function Just on Home Page, Stopped on Others, Restarted When Revisting Home Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a Gatsby site with several pages. On the home page, there's a visual Widget (an animated series of image slices that run continuously) controlled with my program written as external custom javascript modules. The Widget is a React component and it loads the modules and currently fires off the "run" function for the program within the `componentDidMount` method.

This all works great on the initial load of the home page.  But when I go to another page, and the widget is no longer on the page, my javascript program errors out.

What I'd like is for the Widget program to stop or be unloaded when the user goes to another page, but to run again when the user returns to the home page.

The way that pages load in Gatsby is a little odd in this respect; it doesn't work as one might expect coming from a standard html/css/javascript background.

I suspect that the answer lies in React's `componentWillUnmount` method, but nothing I've tried seems to work.

Here's the key bit of the Slices component.

```js
import React from 'react'

import runSlices from '../js/slices/app.js';

[...]

class Slices extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
            runSlices();
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        //Stop (or obliterate) existing function but allow it to be restarted the next time the home page is viewed.
    }


[...]
```

Comment: As you said, it seems related to `componentWillUnmount ` but it's difficult to guess without code. Can you provide your `Layout.js` as well as the home page code?

Comment: Hi Ferran.  I added some code from the Slices component.  Layout and the home page code isn't involved at the moment -- maybe they should be?  But, right now, everything is in the imported modules (slices/app.js) and the Slices component.  The home page code does import and call the Slices component, but does nothing more than that.

Comment: I came up with an inelegant solution which works.  I wrapped every function that touches to DOM in the javascript slices program with try/catch blocks that return if there's an error.